# Filling a glass to about 5 cm ...... top

Tags: prepositions

What is the correct preposition for the following sentence?

> Fill the glass with water to about 5 cm  .....top.

Is it  "off " , "off of" or something different ?

Answer (score 11):

From the.

If you're saying the glass should be filled until there is only 5 cm of space remaining in the top, you want to say:

> Fill the glass with water to about 5 cm *from the* top.

This is a standard usage of distance...

> I am about five feet from the wall.
>   She walked until she was two miles from the office.

With distance, *from* is usually a good bet.

Comment: Thank you. For my example I was wondering if the words "down", "below" or "low" can be correct to use?

Comment: Not low. Down could work in conjunction with "from the". Below would work, too, but "below the top" sounds odd to me; "below the lip/rim" sounds better.

Comment: I'm not sure, but "off the top" might be a substitute for "from the top" in British English. Note in the US, we might tell a barber, "Take a half inch off the top." The phrase is not unheard of, but "from the top" definitely sounds better in regards to a glass.

Comment: @RichF I can't say that I've heard anyone use "off the top" other than for a trip to the barber. That may be the case as it relates to BrE. The OP doesn't specify what variety of English they're using.

Comment: I do not know "off the top" but "from the top" and " below the top" is in use. However  I think " from the top" is much more common according to Google results.

Comment: @RichF In my (Southeastern US) experience, "take an inch off the top" said to the barber means "remove an inch of hair from the top of my head" (top of the head being in contrast to the sides or back). It doesn't describe a distance from the top of my head.

Comment: It may be worth noting that the "from" in this context is interpreted as "away from"

Comment: "Off the top" sounds wrong in BrE, but "off of the top" would be informal (and possibly not very well educated speech). Saying "... to *within* about 5cm *of* the top" would be OK. That may be what you were thinking of.

Comment: @Mrt but it's also used in constructions like "once more, from the top!" meaning start at the beginning of a piece of music, and "take a plate from the top of the stack" whereas "below the top" is in fewer constructions "Below the top flight of Scottish football...". So I wouldn't trust a simple n-gram for this one.